# Using a Getter in Angular 5 and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having a problem setting up a Getter in a Typescript class, and could use some help understanding what I'm missing. I have a class like this:

```
export class Parameter {
    constructor(
        public dataType: string = '',
        public title: string = '',
        public index: string = '',
        public values: Value[] = [],
        public isValid: boolean = false;
    ) {}
}
```

Using this works fine.

The isValid property is currently being set externally, but it is based on the values stored in the "values" array. I was thinking it is silly and inefficient to set this value externally, instead I should just set isValid as a read-only property. Make sense? For purposes of this question, I'll just setup some simple logic. So here is the re-written Class.

```
export class Parameter {
    constructor(
        public dataType: string = '',
        public title: string = '',
        public index: string = '',
        public values: Value[] = []
    ) {}

        get isValid(): boolean {
          return false; 
    }
}
```

When I run the code and try to access isValid from an instantiated Parameter class (which worked fine in the previous example). Now when I examine the class, the isValid property is "undefined". I set a breakpoint in the Getter and the breakpoints never get hit. I must be defining this wrong, or misunderstanding what I'm trying to do here.

Can anyone please help me understand? Thanks!

EDIT: I changed the isValid() code to just return false because my example code was confusing people. Even with it just returning false, it still comes back as "undefined".

Comment: What line are you putting your breakpoints? Not all code paths of `isValid()` return a value. So `isValid` being `undefined` is the expected behavior if `dataType !== 'dateTime'`

Comment: `get isValid(): boolean { return this.dateType === 'dateTime' && this.values[0].value !== ''; }`

Comment: Please see my edits above. I changed my code to just return false from isValid(), but it still returns as undefined.

Comment: Your code works as expected. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxshf5)

Comment: What do you mean by `examine the  class`? It's not just in debugger, is it? You tried assigning instance.isValid to a variable and printing that variable?m, right?

Comment: Both. When I examine the class in Augury for example, I don't see the getter. When I put this in my HTML {{<myObject>.isValid}} I don't get a value. The StackBlitz Jun posted above looks exactly like my code so I'm so confused.

Comment: I assume the code you've posted is a basic example of what you thought the error was. So I can only assume your issue lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If `this.dataType === 'datetime'` is `false` the method will return `undefined` . You have to return `false` in this case.

```
get isValid(): boolean {
        if (this.dataType === 'datetime') {
            return this.values[0].value !== '';
        } 
return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please see my edits above. I changed my code to just return false from isValid(), but it still returns as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your `Parameter` object, i.e., `let p = new Parameter('foo', ...);`.

Functions (including getters/setters) will be undefined if you simply cast from a JSON object:

```
// doesn't work. getter will be undefined.
let p: Parameter = {
    dataType: 'foo',
    ...
};
```

Comment: "When I run the code and try to access isValid from an instantiated Parameter class (which worked fine in the previous example)."